# Use C# variable as HTML elemnt ID (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I create HTML table in the aspx file. (run on a table and for every record I create a row)
I want the any row will get the ID of the relevant record. 
There is option to do that?

```
<% foreach(Person p in DB.persons){ %>
      //create row with p.ID as ID
<% } %>
```

Thank you !!

Comment: Be aware, the `id` attribute of elements in HTML cannot start with with a number.  Therefore if your ID is numeric (which they normally are) make sure you prefix it with something else

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
Response.Write("<table>");

<% foreach(Person p in DB.persons){ %>
   <%  Response.Write("<tr PersonID='" + p.ID + "' />"); %>
<% } %>

Response.Write("</table>");
```

this will add an attribute to the table row you can read later to get the ID back

Comment: The OP is looking to assign to the row's `id` attribute. `PersonId` isn't a valid attribute anyway.

Comment: you can add any attribute you want to a row!?, or any other html element for that matter. I was not 100% sure based on the english in the question :)

Comment: As @Chris highlights, if the HTML was checked against w3c validation then `PersonID` would be flagged as an invalid attribute.  In HTML5 you can use the prefix `data-` on attributes

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%
           if(DB.persons.Count == 0) {
        %>
            <tr><td colspan="3">No records found</td></tr>
        <%
           }
           else {
               foreach(Person p n DB.persons) {
        %>
            <tr id="p_<%= p.ID %>">
                <td><%= p.ID %></td>
                <td><%= p.Name %></td>
                <td><%= p.Address %></td>
            </tr>
        <%
               }
           }
        %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tend never to start an `id` with numbers as I might show other table in the same page, so I always prefix it, that why you will see `p_123` for `id = 123`

Comment: do you mean `if(DB.persons.Count == 0) {`? :-)

Comment: Hi,
I try that and i get error : 
" 'p_<%= p.ID %>' is not a valid identifier."

Comment: @Grundy LOL, YES! Writting without even looking the page :/ - @user3321263 then it's not `ID` that you are passing... add a breakpoint in the `for` and inspect the `p` object. you will see what properties you are getting...

Comment: @balexandre, you're right to never start an `id` with numbers - nothing to do with personal preference... it's actually invalid HTML.

Comment: Hi, it's the id. I check with debug, and I have a cell in table with this id. ( <td><%= p.ID %></td>)  , that work fine.